# Who is the guy on Abso Lutely Productions vanity card?

Tags: production

Tim Heidecker and Eric Wareheim are comedians with lots of shows on Adult Swim. Their production company is Abso Lutely Productions. Their shows often have a vanity card at the end of an episode. In the vanity card some guy in a pink hat is saying, ”Abso-LUTE-ly!” The picture quality looks like early smart phone footage. Does anyone know who this guy is or why he’s in the vanity card?

I do not recognize him and neither Wikipedia entry on the two comedians nor their production company web site mentions who this guy is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Closing Logo website](http://www.closinglogos.com/page/Abso+Lutely+Productions)

> Logo: On a black background, we see a home video (from VHS) of a shirtless man (who looks a lot like Don Johnson with a mullet) wearing a pink hat in the middle of the screen, with the time stamp "JUN, 28 1991" in the bottom right-hand corner of the box. He turns to the camera and says the word "Abso...lutely!". As he says the word, the pink text "ABSOLUTELY" pops up part-by-part below the box.
>
> Trivia: The man in the home video is the father of Tim Heidecker. His "Abso...lutely!" quote comes from a then-15-year-old Tim asking him to sum up his vacation in 2 words.

Apparently Tim's dad looks like Don Johnson with a mullet?

Comment: Or a young Jeremy Clarkson.

Comment: @Joachim 50-50 :)